# Display number of bytes in data set

Tags: ruby, byte

I wrote a program to create histograms of IP addresses, URLs, error codes, and frequency of IP visits, and would like to obtain the size, in bytes, of the data collected for each histogram.  I looked around and saw a bit about the `bytes` method, but can't seem to get it to function.

Any idea on how to do that to this bit of code? I'd like to add the "byte puts" line after displaying the filename in each method.

```
class CommonLog

  def initialize(logfile)
    @logfile = logfile
  end

  def readfile
    @readfile = File.readlines(@logfile).map { |line|
      line.split()
    }
    @readfile = @readfile.to_s.split(" ")
  end

  def ip_histogram
    @ip_count = 0
    @readfile.each_index { |index|
      if (@readfile[index] =~ /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/ )
        puts @readfile[index]
        puts @ip_count += 1
      end
    }
    puts File.basename @logfile
  end

  def url_histogram
    @url_count = 0 
    @readfile.each_index { |index|
      if (@readfile[index] =~ /\/{1}(([a-z]{4,})|(\~{1}))\:{0}\S+/ )
        puts @readfile[index]
        puts @url_count += 1
      end
    }
    puts File.basename @logfile
  end

  def requests_per_hour
    @time_count2 = 0 
    @time_count3 = 0
    @time_count4 = 0
    @time_count5 = 0
    @time_count6 = 0

    @readfile.each_index { |index|
      if (@readfile[index] =~ /\:\d{2}\:/ )
        @new = @readfile[index].split(":")
        if @new[1] == "02"
          @time_count2 += 1
        elsif @new[1] == "03"
          @time_count3 += 1
        elsif @new[1] == "04"
          @time_count4 += 1
        elsif @new[1] == "05"
          @time_count5 += 1
        elsif @new[1] == "06"
          @time_count6 += 1
        end
      end


    }   
    puts "#{@time_count2} instances during hour 2"
    puts "#{@time_count3} instances during hour 3"
    puts "#{@time_count4} instances during hour 4"
    puts "#{@time_count5} instances during hour 5"
    puts "#{@time_count6} instances during hour 6"
    puts File.basename @logfile
  end

  def sorted_list
    @codearray = Array.new
    @http_code_count = 0
    @count200 = 0
    @count304 =0
    @count301 = 0
    @count403 = 0

    @readfile.each_index { |index|
      if @readfile[index] =~ /([2][0][0]")|([3][0][4])|([3][0][1])|([4][0][3])/
        @codearray << @readfile[index]
        @http_code_count += 1
        if @readfile[index] == '200'
          @count200 += 1
        elsif @readfile[index] == "304"
          @count304 += 1
        elsif @readfile[index] == "301"
          @count301 += 1
          elseif @readfile[index] == "403"
          @count403 += 1
        end
      end
    }

    @hash_count = 0
    @frequencies = Hash.new(0)
    @codearray.each { |word| @frequencies[word] += 1 }
    @frequencies = @frequencies.sort_by { |a, b| a}
    @frequencies.each { |word, frequency| @hash_count += frequency}
    @frequencies.each { |key, value| 
      puts "Error #{key} : #{(value.to_f/@hash_count.to_f)*100}%" 
    }
    puts File.basename @logfile
  end

end

my_file = CommonLog.new("test_log")
my_file.readfile
my_file.ip_histogram
my_file.url_histogram
my_file.requests_per_hour
my_file.sorted_list
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Looking at your code I think this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd strongly recommend adding a minimal example of your input data and what you'd like to have returned, and ask for help using regexp and matching patterns, using conditional logic, defining variables and walking arrays. This could be written more simply and flow better. We're happy to help but we need more information to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the number of bytes processed is the entire [size of each log file](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-i-size) you could do something like this:

```ruby
class CommonLog

  attr_reader :bytes_read

  def initialize(logfile)
    @logfile = logfile
    @bytes_read = File.size(logfile)
  end

  # ... now simply print "bytes_read" when desired ...
```

Comment: That works perfectly, but how would I add it to the various methods to get the byte size of their resulting data (I.E. for ip_histogram, the size in bytes of the returned array of strings)?